# Power BI duplicating rows when the column is don't summarize

Tags: unique, primary-key, relationship, powerbi, dax

Referring to the below screenshots. I'm getting duplicated rows [highlighted] when I click on don't summarize option for column `ec`. If I click as sum then the rows remain correct, i.e 6 rows. [Highlighted]

How can I resolve this issue?

Before clicking on Don't Summarize option
[image: Before clicking on Don't Summarize option]

After clicking on Don't Summarize option
[image: After clicking on Don't Summarize option]

Comment: I don't understand what you expect here. If you don't summarize the values, then you'll get a row for every distinct `ec` value. How do you expect to get only 6 rows without some kind of aggregation being applied to `ec`?

Comment: @alexis Olson 003 represents the line item and each line item has different ec value that is coming from other table.. So in the table visualisation I have used this value which is getting summarised where as when I chose to don't summarise I'll get duplicate rows with each line item value... But I don't want the duplicates I just need that ec value for each item..

Comment: Can you edit to include how you want it to look? I'm assuming you want it like your first image, but with different `ec` values. Can you specify what those `ec` values should be?

Comment: Also, it is important to know what your relationship diagram looks like.

Comment: Hi below is the link for the relationship image https://ibb.co/hfCPb8

Comment: and this is how the Table should look like with -> https://ibb.co/fxqcw8   the image refers the ec value for each line item.. this ec value is taken from 2nd table..

Comment: i would be highly thankful to you if you help me sorting this issue...:)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is happening is that you are trying to match the `ec` from another table which is dependent on both the `title` and the `so`, but the relationships are only (and can only be) defined on a single column.

For example, the value `EG-SO-17-18-003` from `open_po_1[so]` is related to `open_po_2[sales_line]`, but the `title` value is not preserved when reaching across tables (since it's not part of the relationship), so it's returning all of the `title` and `ec` values that occur with `open_po_2[sales_line] = "EG-SO-17-18-003"`.

I don't have time to give a solution on how to fix this at the moment, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction until I can come back and give a full answer.